# Displacement current in Gilbert cell mixer

Tags: circuit-design, rf, mixer, gilbert-cell

I'm trying to design a double balanced Gilbert cell mixer as part of a course. I'm having trouble with eliminating the peaking of the switching current. I know that this happens due to the parasitic capacitances of the switching pair, I cannot simply make the device smaller to make the capacitance smaller as it pushes the IIP2 out of the specified limit. I have tried adding an inductor to resonate out the capacitance but it didn't change anything.

This is the circuit:
[image]

The switching pair input is the LO signal below:

[image: LO signal]

And the current in one of the switching devices:

[image]

How would I go about eliminating the effect of the parasitic capacitance?

Comment: Please post a circuit

Comment: Are you doing this in discrete components or on an IC? a discrete Gilbert cell is very difficult, but most people don't have the resources to do this level of IC design (unless this is a simulation).

Comment: Yes, this is a simulation on cadence